# Kill a running node process in windows

Tags: node.js

Am trying to stop a node script from a running node server in windows

an running the script as `node appium -p 3000`

and it will be in running state until it stop
i need to stop this script running in particular situation
in windows how to kill this node script `node appium -p 3000`
i dont need to kill it by using `PID`.is tjere any possible ways to kill the running process

code

```
    var start = spawn('node appium -p 3000', args);
start.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
start.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('ps stderr: ' + data);
});
start.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('process exit code ' + code);
});


function killall(){

start.kill()//is it possible??/
process.exit() //is it also possible??

}
```

Comment: "I dont need to kill it by using PID" - Why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Kill it by PID

  ```
  Stop-Process 3512
  ```
- Kill it by process name

  ```
  Stop-Process -processname node*
  ```
- Make someone else kill it, if it's launched as a `child_process`

  ```
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;

  var child = exec('node appium -p 3000');

  // Kill after 3 seconds
  setTimeout(function(){ child.kill(); }, 3000);
  ```
- Kill itself

  ```
  process.exit();
  ```
- If it's not a background process, kill it with CTRL+C.

You stated in your comment that it is indeed launched as a child process but you need to kill it in another function. This is a question of variable scope. The following will **NOT** work:

```
function launch(){
    var child = spawn(cmd, args);
}

function kill(){
    child.kill(); // child is undefined
}
```

You just need to make sure `child` exists in your scope:

```
var child;

function launch(){
    child = spawn(cmd, args);
}

function kill(){
    child.kill();
}
```

Comment: yes it is launched as a child process..and one doubt is am running (node appium -p 9090)as `var start = spawn(execCmd, args);

  start.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
 console.log(data) 
  });
  start.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('ps stderr: ' + data);
  });
  start.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('process exit code ' + code);
  });`

Comment: i need to kill  this start.kill() in another function is it possbile?

Comment: @Psl it might be better to add that to your question, it's unreadable in a comment.

Comment: @Psl sure it's possible, just define `var start` in a scope that's a parent of both the function you're launching the process in and the function you need to kill it in.

Comment: also process.exit() can i call this to another function?

Comment: You can call `process.exit` from anywhere, it is a built in global variable to node.